# How do you find the last user to access a database and the timestamp of that access?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 database on a Windows Server 2003 machine (yes, we're trying to migrate to a newer box). I can use the following code to see that last time the various databases were accessed:

```
select 
    d.name, 
    x1 = (select X1 = max(bb.xx) 
          from 
              (select xx = max(last_user_seek) 
               where max(last_user_seek) is not null 
          union all 
          select xx = max(last_user_scan) 
          where max(last_user_scan) is not null 
          union all 
          select xx = max(last_user_lookup) 
          where max(last_user_lookup) is not null 
          union all 
          select xx = max(last_user_update) 
          where max(last_user_update) is not null) bb) 
from
    master.dbo.sysdatabases d 
left outer join 
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s on d.dbid= s.database_id 
group by 
    d.name
```

That works fine, but I need to find out which user performed that access. How would I do that?

Comment: Last is in the last person to access the database.  Most recent, I suppose, if you need it in other phrasing?  As for your MRE, I have no idea what data you want.  It's a standard SQL 2005 database, the answer to this question, like the query included in it, are generic and should work for the majority of databases in SQL 2005.

Comment: *"As for your MRE, I have no idea what data you wan"* Yes never mind mine comment i misread the question and query.. And i didn't notice you needed stats data about account access..

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on database auditing. You should be able to do this with the administrator responsiblility.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last accessed date is months ago, and I need to know who did that.  Turning on auditing going forward won't help my situation at all.

Comment: @Alex . . . Ahhh.  It *will* help your situation months in the future.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not really - if I have my way this box will get archived to tape and decommissioned.  As with most production environments, we have change control processes and I'd really like to avoid going through weeks of red tape, meetings with the DBA team, and the CAB to justify enabling auditing.  Government work, ya know?

Comment: To access the old access data, you probably need to trawl through the LOG backups, not sure how much read tape that entails :)